# Can we automate Phonegap application using Appium?

Tags: cordova, appium

I am trying to automate Phonegap application using Appium. Till now I have tried for Android. I am trying to capture element locators using UI Automator viewer & Appium Inspector but I am unable to do so. On the Inspector it is showing only upto WebView, the remaining part I am not able to capture. I think the reason behind this is Phonegap applications are build using HTML.

Also I tried to capture the locators on Browser and then tried to automate using these locators. However it failed saying "Locator not found".

Can you please tell me whether it is possible to automate Phonegap applications using Appium? If so how can we capture locators here?
Thanks,
Priyanka.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap or Cordova generates a hybrid application, to deal with hybrid application using appium you should make sure you have a debug build of the application.

If you do not have a debug build, appium wont be able to locate the webview content.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to inspect properties for elements you can keep the application screen open on device/emulator and open a new chrome browser and type

> chrome://inspect

in URL box. This should show device attached, webview and an Inspect button, clicking on it will open up a new window with page source for the related screen.

In case you want to work with elements in webview through script, switching to webview context would help.

driver.context("WEBVIEW_webviewname"); WEBVIEW_webviewname - name provided to webview for mobile app

Thanks,
Sujata